# Register Mapping and Re-ordering Code

Tags: assembly, mapping, registry, pipeline

A RISC machine’s compiler may do both a mapping of symbolic
registers to actual registers and a rearrangement of instructions for pipeline efficiency. So lets say that we have the following program fragment:

```
LD SR1, A ;load A into symbolic register 1
LD SR2, B ;load B into symbolic register 2
ADD SR3, SR1, SR2 ;add contents of SR1 and SR2 and store in SR3
LD SR4, C
LD SR5, D
ADD SR6, SR4, SR5
```

a. How would I do a register mapping and then any possible instruction reordering to the above code.

b. Starting with the original program, how would I do instruction reordering and then any possible mapping.

In both cases, how can I find out how many machine registries is used and whether or not there has been any pipeline improvements?

Comment: What architecture / microarchitecture is this for?  What do you mean by "register mapping"?  If it's an in-order architecture with multi-cycle latency loads, you should probably do all 4 loads before trying to use any of the load results.

Comment: see edited post, its for a RISC machine

Comment: The Berkeley RISC CPUs didn't name their registers with the SR prefix.

Comment: The question itself is from my textbook, that the exact syntax they use.

Comment: You'll need to ask your teacher then. We don't have your textbook, so we don't what its asking. Your question is impossible to answer without knowing what actual CPU is being used.